# Print out login user data to match login SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo, user-profile

I'm very new to PHP and Mysql I'm writing shopping website for my assignment,

I have my login, registration, and database up and running, and now I'm at the stage that needs to do my User profile page that is required to pull data out from database,

firstly I have this code working as it will pull everything from my table,

```
  <?php
      $sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2';
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if(count($result)) {
          echo '<table><tr>';
          //Heading
          foreach ($rows[0] as $columnName => $value) {
              echo '<th>' . $columnName . '</th>' ;
          }
          echo '</tr>';
          foreach ($rows as $row) {
              echo '<tr>';
              foreach ($row as $value) {
                  echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
              }
              echo '<tr>';
          }
          echo '</table>';
        }
        ?>
```

but my question is how to make it pull out only the one that matching the login SESSION

Here is my SESSION code

```
<?php

session_start();

require '../ppuyakul/php/db_conn.php';

if( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){

    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,username,password FROM assignment2 WHERE id = :id');
    $records->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $user = NULL;

    if( count($results) > 0){
        $user = $results;
    }

}
?>
```

Thanks so much in advance, looking forward for some nice answer ^^"

Comment: Just extend your sql query (`$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2';`) with WHERE checking if id = $_SESSION['user_id'] (`$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];`)

Comment: What exactly ain't working? Your second code preview does seem to filter the assignment2 table for only that of the session.

Comment: @Autista_z Thanks for your reply i will try it out and let u know the result.

Comment: @Cpt.Kangar00 it will print out entire database table from assignment2 =(

Comment: @Autista_z Its' WORKING !!!! by using 

`$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];`

Thanks so much for you help

Comment: @PrinPuyakul I'm glad i helped. So please accept my added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just extend your sql query (`$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2';`) with WHERE checking if id = $_SESSION['user_id'] (`$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];`)

//foreach

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(count($result)) {
      echo '<table><tr><th>Id</th><th>Fullname</th><th>Username</th></tr>';
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.$row["username"].'</td>';
          echo '<tr>';
      }
      echo '</table>';
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it work like a charm ^^"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it work like a charm ^^"
But i have one more quick question wanna ask i try this code but i come up with error 
Notice: Undefined index: ID in 
Notice: Undefined index: fullname in 
Notice: Undefined index: username in 
`<?php
      $sql = 'SELECT * from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

  while ($rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$rows['ID']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rows['fullname']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$rows['username']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>`

Comment: Do you have in your table assigment2 column with name `fullname`?

Comment: yup, I have that in my database,

Comment: Ah. You cant make while like it. `$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns array of results, no concrete result, so you cant use inside while just $rows['id']. Use `foreach` like you was using it above.

Comment: Ahh, I see, just wonder how can i modify that code to display specific data row such as ID, USERNAME, FULLNAME . because now it will print everything that in the assignment2 table including password and other items which i do not want them to show on the page, Thanks again in advance ^^"

Comment: well, then again edit your select. You cas specify wich columns you want to select: `$sql = 'SELECT id, username, fullname from assignment2 WHERE id = '.$_SESSION['user_id'];` or you use edited foreach - look in Answer, i will add it there.

Comment: Ahhh, I see its working as I expected thanks so much for your help I will try to learn it from here, ^^.

you really help me out so much